# Get a list of all the activities placed on the re-hosted workflow designer

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

How do I get a list of all the activities placed on the re-hosted workflow designer in WF 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [WorkflowInspectionServices.GetActivities()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowinspectionservices.getactivities.aspx) to get the child activities.